# Code refactoring for java swing

Tags: java, swing, methods, refactoring

I want to know is it possible to re factor my code in such a way to remove duplication of almost identical statements, bar the variable name and what it is initialized to by using methods. Here is the code in question:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Menu extends JFrame {
  private JButton jbtChoc1 = new JButton("cross.gif");
  private JButton jbtChoc2 = new JButton("nought.gif");
  private JButton jbtChoc3 = new JButton("cross.gif");
  private JButton jbtChoc4 = new JButton("nought.gif");
  private JButton jbtChoc5 = new JButton("cross.gif");
  private JButton jbtChoc6 = new JButton("nought.gif");
  private JLabel foodLabelChoice = new JLabel("Main Dishes");
  private ImageIcon food1Image = new ImageIcon("cross.gif");
  private ImageIcon food2Image = new ImageIcon("nought.gif");
  private ImageIcon food3Image = new ImageIcon("cross.gif");
  private ImageIcon food4Image = new ImageIcon("nought.gif");
  private ImageIcon food5Image = new ImageIcon("cross.gif");
  private ImageIcon food6Image = new ImageIcon("nought.gif");

  /**
   * Constructor for the Menu.
   */

  public Menu() {
    Container cont = getContentPane();
    cont.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));;
    cont.setBackground(Color.white);

    cont.add(foodLabelChoice, BorderLayout.NORTH);


    JPanel girdSetup = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 3, 5, 5));
    jbtChoc1.setIcon(food1Image);
    girdSetup.add(jbtChoc1);
    jbtChoc1.setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.BOTTOM);
    jbtChoc1.setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);

    jbtChoc2.setIcon(food2Image);
    girdSetup.add(jbtChoc2);
    jbtChoc2.setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.BOTTOM);
    jbtChoc2.setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);

    jbtChoc3.setIcon(food3Image);
    girdSetup.add(jbtChoc3);
    jbtChoc3.setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.BOTTOM);
    jbtChoc3.setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);

    jbtChoc4.setIcon(food4Image);
    girdSetup.add(jbtChoc4);
    jbtChoc4.setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.BOTTOM);
    jbtChoc4.setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);

    jbtChoc5.setIcon(food5Image);
    girdSetup.add(jbtChoc5);
    jbtChoc5.setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.BOTTOM);
    jbtChoc5.setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);

    jbtChoc6.setIcon(food6Image);
    girdSetup.add(jbtChoc6);
    jbtChoc6.setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.BOTTOM);
    jbtChoc6.setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);

    cont.add(girdSetup, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  }

  /**
   * Main method for test.
   * 
   * @param args Initial setup.
   */

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Menu frame = new Menu();
    frame.setTitle("Menu");
    frame.setSize(950, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  }
}
```

I want to remove the duplication of the JButton and ImageIcon declaration and their settings within the constructor so that I simply call a single method instead of copy/paste of code.

Comment: You already posted this exact question in the correct place on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/117369/code-refactoring-for-java-swing). StackOverflow is not the place for code reviews only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by wrapping them in arrays, like this:

```
private static final String[] imageNames = {"cross.gif",
                                            "nought.gif",
                                            "cross.gif",
                                            "nought.gif",
                                            "cross.gif",
                                            "nought.gif"};
private JButton[] jbtChocs = new JButton[imageNames.length];
private ImageIcon[] foodImages = new ImageIcon[imageNames.length];

public Menu() {
    /* ... */
    for(int i = 0; i < imageNames.length; i++){
        jbtChocs[i] = new JButton(imageNames[i]);
        foodImages[i] = new ImageIcon(imageNames[i]);
        jbtChocs[i].setIcon(foodImages[i]);
        girdSetup.add(jbtChocs[i]);
        jbtChocs[i].setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.BOTTOM);
        jbtChocs[i].setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
    }
}
```

Since the behavior is the same for all of them, this lets you simply iterate over each object, applying the same actions to each one.